# Java Preprocessor

Tags: java, optimization, preprocessor

If I have a boolean field like:

`private static final boolean DEBUG = false;`

and within my code I have statements like:

`if(DEBUG) System.err.println("err1");`

does the Java preprocessor just get rid of the if statement and the unreachable code?

Comment: "The Java language has no preprocessor," (http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2003/tt0408.html)  Are you talking about the Java Compiler?

Comment: Thanks for the article, I didn't know Java doesn't have a preprocessor. So I am just talking about the compiler.

Comment: It's true that Java doesn't have a preprocessor with the same capabilities as that of C/C++. However it does have annotation processors which offer compile-time processing. See [Oracle's Annotations Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)

Comment: The link above is broken ... it's now https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Most compilers will eliminate the statement. For example:

```
public class Test {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Here I am");
        }
    }

}
```

After compiling this class, I then print a listing of the produced instructions via the `javap` command:

```
javap -c Test
    Compiled from "Test.java"
    public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
    public Test();
      Code:
       0:   aload_0
       1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."":()V
       4:   return

    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
      Code:
       0:   return

    }
```

As you can see, no `System.out.println`! :)

Comment: also, I checked when you have a statement that is something like `if(DEBUG && condition_that_may_be_true) ...`, and if `DEBUG` is always false it cuts it out.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the Java compiler will eliminate the compiled code within `if` blocks that are controlled by constants. This is an acceptable way to conditionally compile "debug" code that you don't want to include in a production build.

Comment: Can you give the Java Language Specification page that states this?

Comment: @Ralph: See [14.21 Unreachable Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.21) for the discussion in the JLS. The bit about the `if` statement is right near the end of that section.

Comment: Page now here for jse7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21  and here for jse5:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.21