# Java If(false) Compile

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a dynamic web project using Tomcat. It is useful to have a global flag that is the only thing I have to change between my development and deployment servers. The biggest use of the flag is with print statements.

```
public class Debug {
    public final static boolean DEVEL = true;        
    public static void print(String message){
        if(DEVEL){
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, will java compile out the print statements. i.e. if the devel tag is false, the messages will obviously not print but will they be included in the class files (devel is final). This is a question of efficiency. I've heard that the java compiler is very smart but will it pick up on this.

Comment: How important is it that the statements be compiled out? Even if they weren't compiled out, checking the value of a boolean variable is pretty cheap (cheaper than the print method call into the Debug class itself ..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344270/java-preprocessor)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use the 'final' attribute (as you did), and it will compile out the code:

`public static final boolean DEVEL = false;`

You can check by grepping the resultant class file for a string that would appear only if the code were compiled.

Comment: Thats what I hoped/ Wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Ooops! The statement "it WILL compile out the code" is allways true in my humble experience, however the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#236365) (and search for `if (DEBUG) { x=3; }`) states expliclty that this optimization is optional, leaving this decision upto compiler implementors... so don't RELY on it for correctness... other than that it makes naf-all difference. Premature optimisation IS evil.

Comment: @corlettk oops is right... I'm usually more circumspect in my assertions, but sometimes I get carried away. I should have put "in my experience..." as a qualifier. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look into this article:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2000/jw-03-javaperf_4.html

The code you presented is called a "dead code" so it will not be included in the compiled class file if you set DEVEL to false it will not be included in the bytecode.

Also, check the command

```
javap -c
```

to see the resulting bytecode of your class.

Comment: +1 for the `javap -c` tip... That's one way to be positive that your java compiler has implemented this optional optimization... and I still reckon that (in all but the most "extreme" circumstances) the point is mute anyway... it's only one instruction per iteration. We've got better things to think about, surely? ;-) Cheers. Keith

Comment: @corlettk - not only that, but even if it is in the bytecode, there's nothing to say it isn't eliminated by the jvm if the code is JIT compiled. Most optimizations will end up running dead code elimination afterwards.

Comment: @cc: I hadn't thought of JIT optimization, which would kick-in if this statement where in a "hot spot". Goes to prove that such micro-opts are very nearly allways COMPLETELY pointless.

Comment: @corlettk: sure - in this context. Still good to know about this stuff when you're developing for mobile platforms and you might not have a JIT :)

Comment: True that. I suppose one must (like the good ole MHz days) pay attention to efficiency when developing for wee mobile processors (or at least this generation thereof)... but remember that Moore's gone burko on mobiles... bang for buck has been doubling about every two years, not three.

Comment: The javap -c helped me diagnose some tricky JPA pre-detach load cases (to determine whether code that looked like it was triggering load was actually used). In some cases, I found for example pre-detach triggering code stored in variables that were never used again, so the compiled removed those lines as revealed in the  javap -c output. Example: [http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/1030](Pre-detach loading: sometimes retrieval by navigation and access not working in if statement)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the compiler *not* compile it out, use this:

```
    public final static boolean DEVEL = Math.random() > -1;
```

The compiler won't know that this is always `true`. (of course use `< -1` for `false`)

I find this trick handy when you want to remove code temporarily without having the compiler complain abut dead code, eg:

```
void myMethod() {
    // temporarily exit early
    if (Math.random() > -1) return;
    // usual code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make it non-final?

Comment: `final` probably helps runtime optimizer. a simpler way is `Boolean DEVEL = Boolean.TRUE` and `if(Boolean.TRUE)`. (but why do you NEED to keep the dead code in class file?)

Comment: I don't see the point. `if (true) return;` compiles even if there is following code. I do that all the time.

Comment: @EJP Just that I have seen "unreachable code" warnings with IDEs - this approach makes them go away.

Comment: So does turning those warnings off. No excuse for writing incomprehensible code IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the compiler remove code like this, however the JIT will effectively remove code which never runs. Assertions is a common use case for this. There may still be a notional cost but generally one not worth worrying about. i.e. less than 1 nano-second.

Answer (score 0):

The cost can be greater if the toString() method of the message is costly. The toString method of a large sql query in a prepared statement caused a heap overflow due to this line. Thus the standard did not remove it.