# (Compiler) else if(true) vs else scenario

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-construction, language-lawyer

Take the following Java code snippet:

```
....
    else if (true){ //hard-coded as true
     ///launch methodA
    }
    else {
     ///launch methodA (same code as in the ` else if ` statement)
    }
....
```

What I was wondering is how the compiler deals with this. Wouldn't it be logical for the compiler to remove the `else if(true)` statement altogether in order to not have to perform a check, even though it is hard-coded as true. Specifically in Eclipse, how is the code above interpreted?

Or what about in the following scenario:

```
....
    else if (true){ //hard-coded as true
     ///launch methodA
    }
    else {
     ///launch methodBB
    }
....
```

Wouldn't it be logical in this case for the compiler to remove the `else` statement? Because while running, the `else` statement is unreachable.

Comment: Just wondering... the most logical (or at least the most efficient) would be the compiler to leave only the `launch methodA`, in both cases.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be logical..."  Yes, and that's what most modern compilers actually do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unreachable statements are forbidden in Java and must trigger compilation errors. The JLS defines what is an unreachable statements:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21

It is too long to be entirely quoted here, but here is an extract (**emphasis** mine):

> ```
> if (false) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> does not result in a compile-time error. An optimizing compiler **may**
>   realize that the statement x=3; will never be executed and **may** choose
>   to omit the code for that statement from the generated class file, but
>   the statement x=3; is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical
>   sense specified here.
>
> The rationale for this differing treatment is to allow programmers to
>   define "flag variables" such as:
>
> ```
> static final boolean DEBUG = false;
> ```
>
> and then write code such as:
>
> ```
> if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
> ```
>
> The idea is that it should be possible to change the value of DEBUG from false to true or from true to false and then compile the code correctly with no other changes to the program text.

So the answer will depend on the compiler you use and its optimization options.

Comment: Beyond that, it would be rather annoying if a programmer who has a variable like `static boolean enableLogging;` which is actually *used as a variable* couldn't later change it to `static final boolean elableLogging = false;` without having to manually edit all the code that reads it.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler optmizes it at compile time:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(true) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Boom");
    }
}
```

Gives me (with my `Java 1.8.0_45`):

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  publicTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1        // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2        // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3        // String Hello
       5: invokevirtual #4        // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

The code just prints `Hello`. `Boom` is not even considered.

All recent Java compilers eliminate dead code at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no particular answer to this question. It depends on the Java Compiler.
Most compilers ignore Dead Code because it will not change the semantic of the code even if it results in a larger class file.

If you are interested in such analysis there is a lot of literature about Dead Code elimination.

Answer (score 3):

You can try writing the code and decompiling the class file. My compiler optimizes

```
else if (true){ //hard-coded as true
 ///launch methodA
}
else {
 ///launch methodA (same code as in the else if statement)
}
```

as

```
else {
 ///launch methodA
}
```

and

```
else if (true){ //hard-coded as true
 ///launch methodA
}
else {
 ///launch methodBB
}
```

as

```
else {
 ///launch methodA
}
```

I think all compiler versions will optimize it in this way.

Answer (score 2):

About Eclipse in particular, it's going to warn you the last else block is unreachable, but compilation is delegated to your jdk, so maybe it is the compiler what warns Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, Eclipse has its own compiler, `ecj` (Eclipse Compiler for Java). Sun's/Oracle's `javac` (written by Martin Odersky, the designer of Scala) is a batch compiler, not designed for interactive, incremental use. `ecj` (like all of Eclipse) is derived from IBM VisualAge for Smalltalk, and thus specifically designed for "while-you-type" interactive, incremental compilation inside an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Now I write codes in eclipse, my method is

```
public static void aa(String b) {
  if (true) {

  } else if (true) {
    System.out.println("asas");
  } else {
  }
}
```

After I compiled my code and I decompile my code with JD-GUI. My decompiled code is:

```
public static void aa(String b) {}
```

result is very good!

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't it be logical for the compiler to remove the else if(true) statement altogether in order to not have to perform a check, even though it is hard-coded as true.

No, it wouldn't, unless both blocks had the same content, and why would it check for that? It would be semantically incorrect. What would be logical would be for the compiler to remove the final unreachable `else`, and that is what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Related answers: [Java If(false) Compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239991/java-iffalse-compile)

See especially remarks about using javap -c to diagnose bytecode to see whether dead code was in fact eliminated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6240017/679457